# Optical properties using ESPRESSO's epsilon.x

Tags: quantum-espresso, k-points, optical-properties

Currently I'm using epsilon.x from Quantum ESPRESSO to analyse optical
properties of metallic alloys. I'm getting a wiggling curve for the dielectric function.

For the imaginary part of dielectric function:
[image]

After some searching, I've found it could be due to the sampling within the Brillouin Zone. I'm using the automatic grid within the denser NSCF calculation. Here is a question:

Can the automatic sampling be the source of the wiggles in the curves? If so, what are the different options to generate the grid?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 Could you please share a sample figure of the wiggling you are getting in the curve, that would make your question more clear. Thanks

Comment: Question edited to include an image of the wiggling curve.

Comment: judging from the figure, it does look like it is due to low resolution in momentum space, tbh I am not QE user, but in general if you have done convergence tests with your kpoint grid that should not be a problem.

Comment: We did all the convergence tests for the resolution within the k mesh. We are using a quite dense uniform grid with 32 points per direction.